# input FormData reactjs hooks

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I'm learning react js, here I am making an input to the database. here I have a problem how to send data with the format FormData ();  use hooks ?

```
const initialFormState = { id: null, id_user: '1', kode: '', qty: '', harga: '' }
  
    const [ibarang, setIbarang] = useState(initialFormState);

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setIbarang({ ...ibarang, [name]: value })

    }

    const handleSubmitBarang = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(ibarang);
        try {
        let res = await Axios.post('https://API.COM', ibarang, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        })
        console.log(res.data)
        if (res.data.status === 200) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                // history.push("/dashboard")
            }, 500);
        } else if (res.data.status === 401) {
            setalertMessage("Username atau password salah!")
        } else {
            setalertMessage("Periksa kembali koneksi internet anda")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        setalertMessage("Periksa kembali koneksi internet anda")
    }

}
```

Comment: What you try to do? send the data to the server?

Comment: posting data, because the backend uses form-data

Comment: well, you can use any package you want to send the data to the server. I would recommend to use something more simple, like axios, to send simple JSON strings. Give it a try.

Comment: I have updated my code above, I mean, how about use
let FormData = require ('form-data');
let data = new FormData ();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the axios NPM package by

```
npm i axios
```

Second, try something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Submit the form data 
axios.post('https://API.COM', 
  JSON.stringify(ibarang)
).then(response => {
  console.log('Submit Success')
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('Submit Fail')
});
```